# How to export React component with props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm studying React.js now could you help me please how can I export React component with props? Something like this:

```js
class Group extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
  };  
  render () {
    return <div>
        <div className='group'>
          <h2>Boys:</h2>
          <GroupList children={
              this.props.children.filter(x => x.sex === 'male')
            } />
        </div>
        <div className='group'>
          <h2>Girls:</h2>
           <GroupList children={
              this.props.children.filter(x => x.sex === 'female')
            } />
        </div>
      </div>
  }
}

React.render(<Group children={children} />, document.body)
```

It should be simple like "export default Group"

Comment: To export a component it is `export default Group`

Comment: @erichardson30 Ok! How can I use it here? http://codepen.io/azat-io/pen/XdZZze

Comment: If you have all your components in a single file you don't need to use it

Comment: @erichardson30 But I have it not in a single file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to create an html element ex : ` and in your React.render should look like :

```
React.render(<Group />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

You shouldn't need to pass any props into your main component.

To export a component there are 2 ways to do so. You can either do

```
export default class Group extends React.Component {}
```

or

```
class Group extends React.Component { 
  ...
}
export default Group;
```

And then you will want to import the other components into the component you are wanting to add them in to.

Example :

```
import Child from './Child.jsx'
class Group extends React.Component { 
   ...
   render() {
     return (
       <Child />
     )
   }
}
export default Group;
```

And child would look like :

```
class Child extends React.Component { 
      ...
}
export default Child;
```

Comment: For example here: http://codepen.io/azat-io/pen/XdZZze. If change ```React.render(<Main />, document.body)``` to ```React.render(<Group children={children} />, document.body)``` - it will works good. What's the best way to solve it?

Comment: The return in your `Main` is wrong. There is no <main></main> html element. It should look like `render() { return ( <Group children={children} /> ) }`

Comment: It's just example. I can rename and give any name to Main component

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGyyOG please see this. This works. I understand it was just an example. But the render method in main was not syntactically correct.

Comment: Haha. It was very simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First thing, never render components in document.body

Second, instead of

```
React.render(<Group children={children} />, document.body)
```

Write,

```
export default Group
```

Comment: It's not a real project. Here for example, how can I do it? http://codepen.io/azat-io/pen/XdZZze

Comment: At the previous comment link to the example of this. But here added Main component which will import Group

Comment: See @erichardson30 answer. You should get the idea. Create 'Card.jsx' with Card class and export statement at end. Create 'GroupList.jsx' and import Card from './Card.jsx' and export default GroupList. Create 'Group.jsx' import GroupList from './GroupList.jsx' and export default Group. Main.jsx will be your entry point & should import Group from './Group.jsx' and contain main class and React.render code and pass const children[] as props to Group component.